# VS setup wizard impairment - maybe an alternative to it?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

Is Visual Studio's Setup Wizard project able to only deploy some of the files only if it finds a certain key into the registry (a) ? If not, then maybe launch another installer file when that certain reg key is present (b) ?

(a) I have been trying to deploy a winamp plugin through VS's .msi files. 2 problems:

- the path to {winamp}/plugins folder has to be obtained automatically
- on failure, user should be presented with a dialog to choose where to install the plugin to

(b) In an attempt to overcome (a) the NSIS installer was used for only packaging the winamp .dll plugin; however, this introduced another issue:

- if user does not have winamp installed, the NSIS generated sub-installer must be manually canceled, and this invariably causes the main VS generated installer to fail (while it shoud not, winamp is not an essential part of the good functionning of the whole app I am deploying)
- I have failed in 2 ways to conditionally launch the sub-installer on a certain reg key detection (tried to look for the ProgID key of Winamp). First failure was because the ProgID key is not found even on machines that do have winamp installed (manually checked for the key, it was there), and second failure was due to the fat that such conditional launch could not be applied to just the sub-installer, but to the main installer only.

I am thinking of dumping the VS project wizard altogether and just move to NSIS installer wizard.. but I would not want to learn to script it for deploying each component of my solution. Any GUI version for it ? Or should I start learning Orca and use it on the VSPW's output .msi file ? Or what ?

Thanks

Comment: u may want to try Wix to create your installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a MSI the approach is this:
- create a search for the registry entry
- use the search result (it's stored in an installer property) to condition the components of your files
- use the same result to condition the installation folder dialog

This can easily be done in commercial setup tools. But if you want a free solution, Sandeep is right, Wix is very good.

Comment: Cosmine, I have tried and retried until exasperation to make VS crafted installer behave the way I wanted it to but have only been able to do so with compromises. Moving to another thing, thanks for suggesting.